# Dividing and counting the booking status in columns

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a breakdown of the status of the booking of our clients. The query works but each column shows the same number. I added a picture to show the result.

```
select distinct client.id,

client.company_name, 

count(CASE WHEN booking.status = 'ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "confirmed",
count(CASE WHEN booking.status = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "cancelled" ,
count(CASE WHEN booking.status = 'BU' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "BU" 

from client

join auth_user on auth_user.id = client.user_id 
join booking on booking.client_id = client.id

where auth_user.date_joined >= '04-01-2021'

group by 1, 2
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `count`, try `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` counts values which are not null. So in your solution every row is counted. You can use conditions instead of `CASE WHEN`:

```
select distinct client.id,

client.company_name, 

count(booking.status = 'ok' OR NULL) as "confirmed",
count(booking.status = 'CA' OR NULL) as "cancelled" ,
count(booking.status = 'BU' OR NULL) as "BU" 

from client

join auth_user on auth_user.id = client.user_id 
join booking on booking.client_id = client.id

where auth_user.date_joined >= '04-01-2021'

group by 1, 2
```

The conditions inside of the count aggregate evaluate to `TRUE` or `NULL`.